# Import Namespace can't find namespace

Tags: asp.net, ascx

I have a usercontrol (ascx) and want to use a namespace which i get with "import":

```
<%@ Import Namespace="my.assembly.blabla.bla.test" %>
```

The namespace definetly exists - it is used in code behind und the dll is referenced in the project.
On run-time i get the error

> The type or nemspace 'bla' does not exist in the namespace 'blabla'
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The strange thing is, when i add a register-directive (which i don't use), then it works. the register directive looks like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xxx" Assembly="my.assembly.blabla,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=373h77ghg78hh478"
Namespace="my.assembly.blabla.bla" %>
```

I don't want to put everywhere an unused register-directive, so does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: not clear question are u facing a problem in using references??

Comment: What does the using directive that works in the code behind look like?

Comment: What exactly is the type that doesn't exist? You've masked all the useful information with words like "bla." Is it the user control itself that doesn't exist? Is it a type within another namespace that you're trying to use **within** the user control?

Comment: Yes, it is a type within another namespace, that i want to use within the user control. the type is a custom type, so the information is not useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to web.config under configuration/system.web/compilation/assemblies:

```
<add assembly="my.assembly.blabla,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=373h77ghg78hh478"/>
```

Like this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="c#" batch="false" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="50" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="my.assembly.blabla,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=373h77ghg78hh478"/>
            </assemblies>
...
```